# enter the number into phone application screen during conversation

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile, android-activity

I want to enter the number into phone application of android phone during conversation by my android program. (like this actions - 1.open dial keypad and 2.typing the number).

For example - when you call the phone number that phone number is an extension phone number.
For eg - (ph no - +6581329445 and ext no - 303)
So, firstly you will need to call the phone number(eg - +6581329445 ) and then you will need to press the desire extension no (eg - 303) after picked up the phone by other side(callee).

I would like to do this step by programmatically.
Now, I can call to the phone number(eg - +6581329445) from my program and then the callee will picked the phone and I will need to input the number of destination extension number(eg - 303) from my program.(likely to dial the destination extension number(eg - 303) in keypad of phone application answering screen during the callee(eg - +6581329445) answering the phone).

Use cases explanation by pictures.

1. Call to hotel phone no (eg - +6581329445)

[image]

2. Enter the room extension no (eg - 303)

[image]

I would like to do step 2 from my program.
Please give me advice and help me how to code this step in android programming. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit better? It is difficult to understand